# Filter array elements based on value of a key element for Given IDs

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON  object  in PHP Like

```
 $my_json = '[{
        "No": "1",
        "Id": "10",
        "msg": "Value is 10"

    },
    {
        "No": "2",
        "Id": "55",
        "msg": "value is 55"

    }, {
        "No": "3",
        "Id": "38",
        "msg": "value is 38 "
    }, {
        "No": "4",
        "Id": "95",
        "msg": "value is 95 "
    } ]';
```

I have converted it to PHP object array using   $obj_arr= json_decode($my_json);

Now, based on user selection I want to filter array element 
Eg. if the user selects "ID" as  38 and 55 then new array should note have ID 10 and 95  IN it and must contain all other data related to those ID just like an original one

EG

```
 $final_json = '[
{
    "No": "2",
    "Id": "55",
    "msg": "value is 55"

}, {
    "No": "3",
    "Id": "38",
    "msg": "value is 38 "
} ]';
```

Comment: Can you please include the PHP code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$my_json = '[{
    "No": "1",
    "Id": "10",
    "msg": "Value is 10"

},
{
    "No": "2",
    "Id": "55",
    "msg": "value is 55"

}, {
    "No": "3",
    "Id": "38",
    "msg": "value is 38 "
}, {
    "No": "4",
    "Id": "95",
    "msg": "value is 95 "
} ]';

$selected = [38, 55];

$obj = json_decode($my_json);

$result = array_filter($obj, function($row) use ($selected) {
    return in_array($row->Id, $selected);
});

echo json_encode(array_values($result), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "No": "2",
        "Id": "55",
        "msg": "value is 55"
    },
    {
        "No": "3",
        "Id": "38",
        "msg": "value is 38 "
    }
]
```

If you want to filter out the selected values above instead of keep them, return the negation of in_array.